# Do remote EXE calls using WMI prevent that EXE from calling other applications?

Tags: wmi, remote-access

I have the following code in my C# application for running EXE’s or any other commands on a remote client. I'm trying not to rely on psexec or other tools.

```
 public static void ConnectToRemoteClient(string client_machine, string target_exe )
 {
     var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
     object[] theProcessToRun = { target_exe };

     var wmiScope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{client_machine}\root\cimv2", connection);

     wmiScope.Connect();

     using (var managementClass = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions()))
     {
         managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun );
     }   
 }
```

A sample of how it’s used is as follows:

```
 string exe = string.Format(@"cmd.exe /c C:\temp\Myfolder\test.bat");
 ConnectToRemoteClient("ClientMachine", exe);
```

The test.bat just echos to a file as a test to see if the remote execute works.

Example:  echo Some text > myfile.txt

It works flawlessly. However, when I use the code to launch an EXE that calls the same batch file, the  EXE gets launched, but the bat file never runs.

If I double-click the EXE directly, it launches the batch file.

So my question is this. Does the WMI functionality prevent the calling of other executables or batches from the original EXE called?

Answer (score 0):

ok. Figured out the issue.
I had to actually cd to the directory first and run it there. It couldn't find it if I just fed it the full path.

```
  string exe = string.Format(@"cmd.exe /c cd C:\temp\Myfolder" + @" &RunTestbat.exe");
```